# AWS Aurora MySQL - Error writing file '/rdsdbdata/tmp/xXx' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

After some search, I understand that the problem is potentially caused by my `SELECT id, name, date, score FROM student_grade ORDER BY  id, date DESC`query, which creates a temporary table. As the in-memory table size is too small, it has to be written on disk. And the table file is somehow limited, thus the error.
Here are my findings so far:

- Cleaning up `rdsdbdata/tmp` is a no-go, as this is not really manageable with RDS
- The RDS instance itself has plenty of disk space so the actual disk space should not be an issue. With `innodb_file_per_table` set to `ON`, I guess each table has its own tmp file, of which the size is limited?
- Increasing `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` (defaulted at 16MB) would maybe do the trick. I don't know how big is enough though, any recommended size? (some says it should be 1% of `DBInstanceClassMemory`). Anyway, I created some modified parameter group and configure the db instance to use it. Somehow, the tmp table size remains default (16MB). I'm stuck here too.
- Without the `ORDER BY` part, the query works. So the sorting seems to be the issue here, is there a work around?
- The output text file of the query (without the `ORDER BY` part) is roughly 500MB (~200 millions records), should it be the size to set for the tmp table?

So, I've tried everything I could and I think I'll contact cloud team to help with configuration. But other than that, is there any MySql configs should I be tinkering with? Or any sql optimisation I should do with my query?

Comment: Depending on the query, you might optimize it by making sure the rows are read in index order matching your desired sort order. Then it doesn't need to sort on disk or in memory, it just returns the data in the order it reads them. But there's no way to recommend an index since you don't show the query you're trying to run. And not all queries can be optimized in this way.

Comment: Another suggestion is to generate smaller result sets. That is, fewer matching rows to sort means smaller sort buffer. That should either fit in memory, or at least take less space on storage.

Comment: @BillKarwin The query is actually very simple, it looks like `SELECT id, name, date, score ORDER BY  id, date DESC`  where id is `string` and date is `integer` (e.g. `20211129`).  There are nearly 200 millions records.

Comment: No `FROM` clause or `WHERE` clause? What purpose is there to fetch 200 million rows? No wonder it's running out of space sorting it.

Comment: @BillKarwin My bad, let's say `FROM student_grades`. This query is used by a .NET application to export all records to a text file, thus, no `WHERE`.

Comment: @BillKarwin Ok, so based on your suggestion, I guess I can add an index for these 2 columns with proper sorting: `CREATE INDEX index1 ON student_grades (id ASC, date DESC)`. Then in the `SELECT` query, I no longer need to call `ORDER BY` clause. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

All InnoDB queries should read rows in index order, so if you can make it read from an index whose order matches the ultimate order you want, then the `ORDER BY` will be a no-op, and it won't need to sort anything. It'll just return the rows in the order it reads them.

So you would need the table to have an index with columns `(id, date)` as the leftmost columns of the index. But unfortunately MySQL doesn't support indexes with both ASC and DESC columns until version 8.0, and there isn't a version of Amazon Aurora based on MySQL 8.0 yet.

```
ALTER TABLE student_grades ADD KEY `my_new_index` (id ASC, date DESC);
```

MySQL 5.7, which Aurora is based on, can only make indexes with ASC columns.

So you have to change the sort order of the result if you want it to use an index. Either `ORDER BY id DESC, date DESC` or `ORDER BY id ASC, date ASC`. Either will use the index.

Also you probably have to force the query to use the index, because if you're fetching all the rows, it'll default to a table-scan, skipping the index.

```
mysql> explain select * from student_grades force index (my_new_index) order by id desc, date desc \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: student_grades
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: my_new_index
      key_len: 133
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2048
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
```

What I'm looking for in this EXPLAIN report is the *absence* of "Extra: Using filesort".

Comment: Hmm, both cols in the same decreasing or ascending order would mismatch the original requirements unfortunately. So there's really no way to make this work with both ASC and DESC in the same index?

Comment: No, not in the version of MySQL that Aurora is based on. If you try to create an index with the DESC option, it won't return an error but the DESC option is ignored. You can SHOW CREATE TABLE and see that the option is not saved.

Comment: So if indexes are created for both cols, even there is still `order by` in the query, there's no temp table created, correct?

Comment: It's not a temp table per se regardless. It's called the sort buffer. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Wait, if this is caused by the mysql's `filesort` operation then it has something to do with `sort_buffer_size` instead of `tmp_table_size`?

Comment: Yes. Rows are sorted in memory if possible, in a buffer up to `sort_buffer_size` in bytes. If it's too large to do that, it sorts a subset of rows, as much as can fit in that buffer, and saves each sorted subset to disk. Once it has saved all these batches of rows in sorted format, it can make a final result set by merging them. Merging multiple sorted sets is easier than sorting.

Comment: You can monitor `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'sort_merge_passes'` to find out how many of these batches were processed in your session. Read that status value before and after doing your big query.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the same error and I fixed my issue by reading this blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-configuring-parameters-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql-part-1-parameters-related-to-performance/. I then changed the **tmp_table_size**, and **max_heap_table_size** to the recommended 64MB. You can do this in Aurora by creating a new DB cluster parameter group for your DB version. Then, you search for those two variables, click edit, and modify them to **67,108,864** bytes (64 MB), 128 MB, or 512 MB as the documentation recommends. Then, assign that parameter group to your database and apply the changes. For my purposes, 64 MB for those variables was more than enough.